# Which is the proper point of contact with the bench in bench press?

Tags: bodybuilding, powerlifting, bench-press, chest

When I perform the bench press, and all similar exercises where it is usefult to brace against the bench (by thinking of squeezing the its fabric), such as dumbbell inclined press etc, **I feel a stabbing pain** in my midback, near the bottom of my left shoulder-blade in the point shown below.

[image]

If I give up performing such exercises, and replace them with others with again shoulder-blades back and down but without bracing against the bench (for instance all cable fly variations), I do not have this kind of pain.

Unfortunately all the physical therapists I've seen weren't able to solve this problem as it is very specific for those exercises where I brace against a bench.

So I was thinking: what if my setup was wrong? My actual point of contact with the bench in those exercises are the middle of the shoulder blades. Is it correct? Or is the proper point of contact-pressure the rear delt?

I tried to touch the bench higher, so that my rear delt was the point of contact. It appears to cause less pain but probably my thoracic extension is not sufficient for that arch and I arch my lower back more to achieve that position.

Also if I lie flat in the bench the situation improves, although there is a little amount of pain. I think it improves because there is less (but non-zero) pressure on my trigger point.

Do you have any advices?